# How Can I Ask for an Expert Opinion Without Getting My Question Put On Hold for Soliciting Opinions?

Tags: support

Recently [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495125) about the von Neumann Interpretation of QM (a.k.a. the Consciousness Causes Collapse Hypothesis, CCCH) was put on hold within days of being asked. The reason given was that it was "primarily opinion based".

Technically, of course, the moderators are correct; but, I think the real problem is that the question cries out for **expert** opinion yet, judging from their profiles, none of those who have commented are claiming credentials as physicists. (Please note that I am not a physicist either. What I would have contributed had the question not been put on hold was the following information which, I hope, will indicate why expert opinion is needed).

The question cited refers us to an article on arXiv that was subsequently published in Foundations of Physics, a respectable, peer-reviewed journal if I am not mistaken. However, despite the title of the question that was put on hold, the article in Foundations of Physics only mentioned Henry Stapp's theory involving the Quantum Zeno effect in passing. The authors (physicists de Barros, J. Acacio and Oas, Gary) actually proposed an experiment to test the CCCH using trained cockroaches. They then argued that the experiment would inevitably fail and concluded that the CCCH is unfalsifiable.

How do I open a new question wherein I posted the information in the last paragraph and ask for **expert** opinions as to the validity of the reasoning leading to the conclusion mentioned -- **without** having the question put on hold for soliciting opinions?

Comment: Relevant: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: It is worth noting that the culture of the site does not encourage users to present any credentials they may hold (and I think that the site is largely better off for it). I know that we have a number of users either holding advanced degrees or currently in school working toward one who give no hint of it in their profiles. In other cases, you can deduce that a user is credentialed from their profile but they don't say so explicitly.

Comment: If really someone is interested in “expert opinions”,  the question is *ipso facto* opinion-based.   Moreover I’ll wager everyone posting a question expects an “expert” answer, be it at a level commensurate with the question.